# rxvt-unicode doesn't scale on HiDPI screen

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnome, rxvt

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell XPS 9350 "13.3 with 3200x1800 resolution. When I start rxvt-unicode it's so scaled out that it's not possible to read anything. I've solved that in other apps by setting `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1`, but I guess rxvt-unicode doesn't use QT. I've tried with adding the following to ~/.Xresources but without any effect.

```
Xft.dpi: 276
```

I've no clue how to get further. What widget framework (like QT) are rxvt-unicode using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rxvt-unicode runs on top of libX11, it doesn't use any high-level UI library like GTK, Qt, fltk, etc.

To deal with this issue, install the terminus font and set it in `~/.Xdefaults`:

```
URxvt.font: xft:Terminus:pixelsize=32:antialias=false
URxvt.depth: 32
```